# Webpack module federation error: Cannot destructure property `ModuleFederationPlugin` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: yarnpkg, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I am currently modifying the configuration file a Vue app (acting here as a host app) to implement the plugin of webpack : ModuleFederationPlugin.
The goal for me is to set up a micro-frontend architecture by getting a component from a remote app called "foo".

Here is the code to reproduce the issue :

- config file host app :

```
const path = require("path");
const helpers = require("./config/helpers");
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require("webpack").container;

const config = {
  configureWebpack: {
    entry: {
      polyfill: "@babel/polyfill",
    },
    stats: {
      cached: false,
      cachedAssets: false,
      chunks: false,
      chunkModules: false,
      chunkOrigins: false,
      modules: false,
    },
    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true,
      port: 8765,
    },
    plugins: [
      new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: "vue",
        remotes: {
          foo: "foo@http://localhost:5173/remoteEntry.js",
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
  pluginOptions: {
    "style-resources-loader": {
      preProcessor: "scss",
      patterns: [],
    },
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

- package.json host app :

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test",
  "author": "Test",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.7.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.6.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.7.1",
    "@babel/register": "7.7.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.0.5",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "5.2.0",
    "cache-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "0.9.6",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "karma-webpack": "4.0.2",
    "selenium-server": "3.141.59",
    "url-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-style-resources-loader": "^0.1.4",
    "vue-loader": "15.7.2",
    "vue-style-loader": "4.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.10",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.2.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 8.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 5.0.0"
  }
}
```

yarn version host app : 1.22.19
node version host app : v12.0.0

- config file remote app :

```
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr"
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react"
import * as path from "path"
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation"

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    svgr(),
    react(),
    federation({
      name: "foo",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./App": "./src/App.tsx",
      },
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    target: "esnext",
    assetsDir: "assets",
  },
  server: {
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    port: 5173,
  },
})
```

- package.json file of the remote app :

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "author": "test",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "build:prod": "tsc && vite build",
    "build:demo": "tsc && vite build --mode demo",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "lint:check": "eslint \"./src/**/*.{ts,tsx}\"",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix \"./src/**/*.{ts,tsx}\"",
    "prettier:check": "prettier --check .",
    "prettier:fix": "prettier --write ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.9",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.0",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.0",
    "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation": "^1.1.11",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.5",
    "i18next": "^21.8.14",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "npm": "^8.19.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-charts": "=3.0.0-beta.30",
    "react-confetti": "^6.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.33.1",
    "react-i18next": "^11.18.1",
    "react-number-format": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.7.18",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.30.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.30.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.20.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4",
    "vite": "^3.0.0",
    "vite-plugin-svgr": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

yarn version of the remote app : 1.22.19
node version of the remote app : v12.0.0

Here is what I get when running the host app with "yarn serve" :
[error logs when launching the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMeJ5.png)

My goal is then to be able to use the component App from the remote app in the host app by importing it like that :

```
Vue.component("App", () => import("foo/App"));
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.